# Django package for linking user to FB account

Tags: python, django, facebook, authentication, django-socialauth

What is the most appropriate Django package for linking regular Django user to FB account?
Scenario:

1. User of regular Django site registers an account
2. He logs in using plain login/password
3. He connects his regular account to FB account and able to re-link later it to different FB account if needed.

I can't seem to find a package that matches all of the requirements, seems that most packages(django-facebook, django-social-auth) assume
that initial login/registration to site is done through social media, while all I want is - regular django login and some optional/delayed access to social media.

Answer (score 5):

django-social-auth should let you do what you want, since it allows multiple social accounts (e.g. Facebook, LinkedIn, etc...) to be associated with a single Django user (the core auth.User, not a custom user class like some other apps use).

I would look at django-social-auth's [pipeline feature](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html#partial-pipeline) and use the `social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user` function to associate a Facebook account to an existing User.

Comment: is there an update to this answer or an article that explains how to this in more depth? Also the link is broken.